# coresphere /console-bundle not found in appkernel.php in line 33

Tags: symfony

I recently installed and configured coresphere/console-bundle and I registered the bundle in `routing_dev.yml` :

```
_console :
resource: "@CoreSphereConsoleBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
prefix: /_console`
```

When I run the code I have this error:

> Fatal error: Class 'CoreSphere\ConsoleBundle\CoreSphereConsoleBundle' not found in C:\wamp\www\Symfony2.8.2\app\AppKernel.php on line 33

Anyone can help me ?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a part of [the installation chapter](https://github.com/CoreSphere/ConsoleBundle#installation).

In your `app/AppKernel.php`, register the bundle :

```
// app/AppKernel.php
public function registerBundles()
{
    // ...

    if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), ['dev', 'test'])) {
        // ...
        $bundles[] = new CoreSphere\ConsoleBundle\CoreSphereConsoleBundle();
    }

    // ...
}
```

Don't forget to clear your cache.

Comment: Did you correctly executed ´composer update´ after adding the bundle to the  ´require´ block of your composer.json  ?

Comment: ok you are right now i tried with composer.phar update and all is ok

Comment: If I solved your problem you can mark your question as answered